# Open firefox window in selenium with firefox addons loaded?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

when I run my test in selenium, the newly opened firefox window is opened without my installed addons like xpathchecker.

Is it possible to setup selenium so that it will use firefox with installed addons?

Comment: How are you launching firefox, using selenium-remote control(rc) ?

Comment: Iam using sharp develop to edit and to run selenium c# scripts via nunit modul... selenium RC need to be only installed on your hardware

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using selenium remote control,

1. you might need to [create a separate profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing+profiles) for testing with your addons.
2. After that you can install the addons in that new profile. Note down the path of the profile folder in profile manager or check here to locate your [profile folder](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles)
3. Then when you start selenium, use

   -firefoxProfileTemplate "path to the profile"

to specify the location of the profile with addons installed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add. When running RC from java you can use:

```
RemoteControlConfiguration server_preferences = new RemoteControlConfiguration();  
File f = new File('/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/qa/'); // 'qa' is my profile folder name
server_preferences.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(f);  
(...)   
myServer = new SeleniumServer(server_preferences);  
myServer.start();
```