# How to use a certain Firefox profile in Python Selenium binding?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm looking for a solution similar to presented in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138953/open-firefox-window-in-selenium-with-firefox-addons-loaded), except it has to deal with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer that was accepted is language agnostic. You will need to setup a firefox profile then when starting up selenium rc tell it to use that profile.

You just need to run your tests to use `*firefox` against the rc that has your profile and when the browser loads it will be the one you are after