# Firefox started by selenium is not the same as manually started

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have installed some plugins,for examples,Selenium IDE,Thender Extention in Firefox.
But when I use selenium to start Firefox,the Firefox only display Firefox WebDriver in Extensions page.
below is my java code:

```
ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);  
firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();  
MyLog.logger.info("Initializing the Firefox webdriver...");  
driver =new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
```

Now I can start firefox in seleinum with Add-ons loaded at [start firefox   with default profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328494/selenium2-firefox-use-the-default-profile#7341831)

Besides,when I open the same web page,firefox started by selenium shows errors in Error Console:

```
NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED
```

Comment: It probably uses a separate [Firefox profile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Multiple_Firefox_Profiles) from your default one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open firefox window in selenium with firefox addons loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138953/open-firefox-window-in-selenium-with-firefox-addons-loaded)