# I am using RSelenium and I would like to be able to load up an addon upon initiation

Tags: r, firefox, selenium

I would like to be able to use R to remote drive Selenium while the Firefox Add-On "anonymoX" is loaded.

I see there are similar threads discussing add-ons with Selenium:

[How do you use a firefox plugin within a selenium webdriver program written in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j)

[Open firefox window in selenium with firefox addons loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138953/open-firefox-window-in-selenium-with-firefox-addons-loaded)

But nothing with regards RSelenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the add-on in the firefox profile before the webdriver invokation. Please mention the problem that you are facing. Can guide with the code accordingly.