# Open Firefox Profile with privatebrowsing in Selenium

Tags: java, maven, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have many profiles in Firefox to open in selenium, now i want to open a Firefox profile in Private Browsing Mode. How to Open Firefox Profile with privatebrowsing in Selenium? here is my code

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("1");
ffprofile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
driver.get("http://proxy.cm/");
try {Thread.sleep(13000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

this line shows error

```
ffprofile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True);
```

above line show error "True cannot be resolved to a variable".

One more problem i am facing that Selenium is not updating Firefox 
profiles, i mean i installed some new extention, i also changed some 
setting in firefox profile but Selenium always open Firefox with old settings, extensions. 
how can i force Selenium to open firefox profile with updated new settings and extentions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is not Java, but Python (I think).

```
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
```

Note the difference in `setPreference` and `true`.

And for the second problem you can specify the path to the version you want

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path_to_firefox"));
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("1");
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, ffprofile);
```

Another option is to define the path for Firefox in System property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/Applications/Firefox-2.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
```

Comment: and about 2nd problem i am reading here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138953/open-firefox-window-in-selenium-with-firefox-addons-loaded , can you plz help me accourding to my given code? in that question they are using something RemoteControlConfiguration

Comment: @Shumaila I added solution for the second problem.

Comment: sir, what path i have to use in Binary? my profile path or something else? my profile path is C:\\Users\\Shum\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\qrxeiurf.1

Comment: @Shumaila You need to use the browser path

Comment: @Shumaila I added second option

Comment: ok thanks i am trying to find what is binary path of my firefox.